# Docker container not being removed when using an alias

Tags: docker, terminal, command-line-interface, alias, zshrc

I have a django cookie cutter with docker project and the cli prefix for executing commands is `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml run --rm django python manage.py`. As you can see this is very long so I created a .zshrc alias for this.

For some reason when I run the alias for this command, the container is created, run and exited but not removed from docker desktop. If I run it straight in the terminal, it does the same but the container is removed this time. Any one know why this is or if I can fix this? I don't want to have to type out this super long command, but I also don't want to have to keep deleting dangling containers.

Comment: `-f docker-compose.yml` should be the default and you shouldn't need to specify this.  If `manage.py` is executable and has a correct shebang line, you shouldn't need to explicitly say `python` either.  Does that bring the command line down to something more reasonable; `docker compose run --rm django ./manage.py ...`?

Comment: That works! Thanks! Any idea why it leaves the containers when the command is run using an alias?

Comment: Questions about shell aliases might be better asked on [unix.se]; that's not really a programming-related question.